# Undefined symbols in Scipy and Scikit-learn on RedHat

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, atlas

I'm trying to install Scikit-Learn on a 64-bit Red Hat Enterprise 6.6 server on which I don't have root privileges.  I've done a fresh installation of Python 2.7.9, Numpy 1.9.2, Scipy 0.15.1, and Scikit-Learn 0.16.1.  The Atlas BLAS installation on the server is 3.8.4.

I can install scikit-learn, but when I attempt to import it in Python, I get

```
File "<pyinstall>/site-packages/scipy/parse/linalg/isolve/_iterative.so: undefined symbol: slamch_"
```

Similarly, when I run

```
>>> import scipy; scipy.test()
```

I get 16 errors, 14 of them ImportErrors for the following undefined symbols:

- `scipy/cluster/_vq.so: undefined symbol _gfortran_st_write_done`
- `scipy/special/_ufuncs.so: undefined symbol dstevr_`
- `scipy/linalg/_fblas.so: undefined symbol csyr_`
- `scipy/lib/blas/fblas.so: undefined symbol slamch_`
- `scipy/lib/lapack/flapack.so: undefined symbol sgbsv_`
- `scipy/spatial/qhull.so: undefined symbol _gfortran_st_write_done`

**My research**
Several sources I've found suggest that issues like this occur because of a mismatched Fortran compiler in compiling the BLAS/LAPack libraries and scipy, e.g. [this mail exchange](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2009-January/019411.html) and another from 2007 (not linked because my reputation isn't high enough to include another link; it referenced the _gfortran_st_write_done symbol).  However, the BLAS build was done on a server that only has gfortran installed (no g77 or Intel compilers), and I recompiled scipy to explicitly use gfortran.

The scipy installation notes also mention that the LAPACK version that comes with Atlas BLAS is not a full implementation, and says that ImportErrors may occur if the installed LAPACK is missing some functions.  So, I followed the instructions [here](http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/errata3.8.4.html#completelp) to install the full version of LAPACK 3.5.0, also compiled with gfortran.  I then recompiled scipy and sklearn pointed at the updated libraries, and received the same import errors.

**My question**
Is there anything that might be causing these errors other than mismatched Fortran compilers?  Alternatively, is there another library I need to be recompiling?

Comment: The second mail exchange, referencing _gfortran_st_write_done symbol, is [here](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2007-December/014944.html).

Comment: Have you tried just using anaconda instead of compiling everything yourself?

Comment: That actually works perfectly, thanks.  I wish I'd thought of that sooner!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Andreas Mueller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/676634/andreas-mueller) for the tip: doing a local install of [anaconda](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/index.html) to a directory I owned got around the compilation issues.