# Error compiling C code for python hmmlearn package

Tags: python, c, compilation, pip, hmmlearn

I'm having some trouble getting the `hmmlearn` package to install properly (in a virtual environment); it seems to have something to do with the underlying C code. The package installs fine with `pip`, but when I try to import the core class, I get an error:

```
In [1]: import hmmlearn

In [2]: from hmmlearn import hmm
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-8b8c029fb053> in <module>()
----> 1 from hmmlearn import hmm

/export/hdi3/home/krono/envs/sd/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hmmlearn/hmm.py in <module>()
     19 from sklearn.utils import check_random_state
     20
---> 21 from .base import _BaseHMM
     22 from .utils import iter_from_X_lengths, normalize
     23

/export/hdi3/home/krono/envs/sd/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hmmlearn/base.py in <module>()
     11 from sklearn.utils.validation import check_is_fitted
     12
---> 13 from . import _hmmc
     14 from .utils import normalize, log_normalize, iter_from_X_lengths
     15

ImportError: /export/hdi3/home/krono/envs/sd/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hmmlearn/_hmmc.so: undefined symbol: npy_expl
```

I've been reading other questions on SO which seem to treat this, but [one solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30428278/undefined-symbols-in-scipy-and-scikit-learn-on-redhat) (use Anaconda) won't work since `hmmlearn` isn't included. It seems like the answer has something to do with compiling the C code, but I'm not sure how to go about it. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Seems like you are using a virtual environment?

Comment: Yup, added that to the question. The install is into a virtual environment.

Comment: Try running uninstalling the package and then run `pip install --no-cache-dir hmmlearn`

Comment: Wow! That worked. Can you explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue a while ago and found the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35123700/3846213) by trying everything possible. For whatever reason in some cases `pip` skips building C-extensions, when a package is saved into the cache directory. If you force `pip` to ignore the cache, it always builds the package from scratch, so the solution is to uninstall the package in the first place and then run `pip install --no-cache-dir <package>`